# Datatables requesting unknown parameter '0' for ajax source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I'm trying to implement a simple ajax [Datatable](http://datatables.net/). For my javascript I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // dynamic table
        oTable = jQuery('#CzmCS5bG').dataTable({
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "sAjaxSource": "http:\/\/localhost\/art\/public\/api\/v1\/clients\/10254\/holdings",
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "iDisplayLength": 100,
                        "paging": false,
                        "searching": false,
                        "info": false,
                        "columns": [{"data:":"ips_asset_id"},{"data:":"sedol"},{"data:":"description"},{"data:":"value"}],          
        });
```

The URL for `sAjaxSource` returns a json object like the following:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ips_asset_id": 134,
            "sedol": "3144206",
            "description": "iShares PLC iShares S&P 500 UCITS ETF (Inc)",
            "name": "iShares S&P 500",
            "subsector": "Equity LO",
            "sector": "Equity",
            "ips_beta": 1,
            "holding_date": "2014-04-30",
            "value": "160795.20"
        },
        {
            "ips_asset_id": 83,
            "sedol": "B3BTVJ2",
            "description": "Schroder International Selection Fund Schroder ISF Asian Total Return GBP C Distribution",
            "name": "Schroder Asian Total Return",
            "subsector": "Equity LO",
            "sector": "Equity",
            "ips_beta": 1,
            "holding_date": "2014-04-30",
            "value": "56397.50"
        }, ...
}
```

However, I get the following error on page load:

> DataTables warning: table id=mytable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0

From looking at my json object there is no parameter 0 in it. Why is this error occurring? My table has 4 columns which is the same number as is requested from the json object.

Comment: Arrgh, just figured it out - I had a `:` after each `data` column key